# Image not found error when starting a simple kivy app

Tags: python, kivy

I recently started using kivy and as I gradually learned the language, I wanted to use images.
I then tried the following program:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class ImageTestApp(App):
    def builder(self):
        image_app = Image(source='on.png')
        return image_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ImageTestApp().run()
```

The source image `on.png` is in the same directory as the file containing the code.

When I run this program, I get the following error :

```
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <on.png>
```

I tried to put the whole path but I still get the same error.

I can't understand why the image is not found, can you help me?

Comment: No way to load your image at all using this sample code. Your `builder` metod is not called at all, that's no way to get imge not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`build`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html?highlight=build#kivy.app.App.build) function, it Initializes the application.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class ImageTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        image_app = Image(source='on.png')
        return image_app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ImageTestApp().run()
```

Comment: I am a little ashamed of my mistake but thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple just like
In kivy file
Image: (enter)
(One tab) source: Images(enter two slash instead one)picname.png

With two slash this problem will solve